# 31.0.0 is not a valid SDK Version. Options are 32.0.0 UNVERSIONED

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am unable to run my app on my simulator as well as device.Earlier it was working.

I have tried every step mentioned in this blog

[Official Blog for updation](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-v31-0-0-is-now-available-cad6d0463f49)

My `package.json` is

```
{
"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
"android-windows": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file App.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && react-native run-android",
"start": "expo start",
"android": "expo start --android",
"ios": "expo start --ios",
"eject": "expo eject",
"debugWindow": "start 'rndebugger://set-debugger-loc?host=localhost&port=8081'",
"debugLinux": "open 'rndebugger://set-debugger-loc?host=localhost&port=8081'"
 },

"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^31.0.4",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-31.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

And `App.json` is

```
{


 "expo": {
    "name": "AwesomeProject",
    "slug": "AwesomeProject",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "31.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried running `npm install` 2-3 times but nothing seems to work.

I can't understand why its been suggesting **option 32.0.0** when there is no **release notes** for this option at this link.
 [Upgrading Expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v31.0.0/workflow/upgrading-expo)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a known issue https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/3112

It is due to the Expo application from the Play Store having a bug. If you are using `v2.10.0` then you should upgrade to `v2.10.1`

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/3112#issuecomment-451697372

> Sorry guys for the trouble  We've fixed this issue in v2.10.1 that
>   was released just a few hours later so you should already have an
>   update.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=host.exp.exponent&hl=en

> **WHAT'S NEW**
>
> Fix issues when loading experiences with SDK older than 32

Comment: In order to uninstall Expo on Android emulator, click and hold the Expo app icon (not the shortcut) and then drag to the Uninstall drop zone. Expo will automatically reinstall itself when you click 'Run on Android device/emulator'

Comment: i have the same error, and no update from the playstore... :(

Comment: @Manoj I am surprised that you are getting this particular error as this error was caused by a specific app store release back in January. The subsequent app release fixed the error. You may get a similar error but that is usually due to the fact that the Expo app you are using doesn't support the version of the SDK you are trying to run. This is caused by either the code being too old for the app (so you have to update the code to the latest SDK) or by the app being too old for the code (so you have to update the app from the playstore).

Answer (score 3):

You can downgrade it by changing those files that refer to version 32 to the one that your mobile supports like 28:

app.json :

`"sdkVersion": "32.0.0"` → `"sdkVersion": "28.0.0"`

package.json :

`"expo": "^32.0.0",` → `"expo": "28.0.0"`
`"react-native": ".../sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",` → `"react-native": ".../sdk-28.0.0.tar.gz"`
`"jest-expo": "^32.0.0"` → `"jest-expo": "28.0.0"`

Answer (score 2):

try updating your expo application from the play store. It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I fixed mine in case any of the above answers don't work for you.

Open up your `app.json` and `sdkVersion`. It was `33.0.0` before upgrading it as below fix the issue.

```
    "sdkVersion": "35.0.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it for me:

Run `expo update 35.0.0`. (Replace version with your desired version. 35.0.0 is the latest as of this post.) This updates expo, by updating app.json & package.json and installing the latest dependencies.

Referenced from:

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/

Also, check that:

- your expo app is the latest version through the app/play store.
- your expo cli is the latest version `npm install -g expo-cli`

Answer (score 0):

If you have run `expo update 35.0.0` or other version and it did not solve the error, and if you had ejected your expo project...

Check if you have the right detach properties in your `app.json`. Note the sdk number on the URL for both `iosExpoViewURL` and `androidExpoViewURL` keys.

```
"detach": {
  "iosExpoViewUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/exp-exponent-view-code/ios-v2.13.0-sdk35.0.0-a30ebc9b-3db4-42f4-b677-e468076baf18.tar.gz",
  "androidExpoViewUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/exp-exponent-view-code/android-v2.13.0-sdk35.0.0-b816b7af-88da-4ca9-87a5-7438f0c21b6e.tar.gz"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
expo update
```

Its Working on my case :)

Answer (score 0):

Clear all data and cache of Expo app on your android device. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the Expo app, update them, because the SDK is not are updated

I updated it, and it worked :)

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json

change from

```
    "expo": "^31.0.0",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-31.0.0.tar.gz",
```

To

```
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
```

Delete node_module folder and package-lock.json file

Then run

```
npm i
```